# How to print (or store) gps lat, lng value (TinyGPS++) with Bluetooth BLE nRF8001?

Tags: arduino-uno, gps

I have a u-blox gps module and I use TinyGPS (http://arduiniana.org/libraries/tinygpsplus/) to get out the lat + lng.

If i write...

```
Serial.println(gps.location.lat(), 6);
```

...out in the log I get the correct latvalue. 
Right now I however work with a BLE (https://www.adafruit.com/product/1697) and when I try to print it like this:

```
BTLEserial.print (gps.location.lat()`, 6);
```

I get a error: `no matching function for call to 'Adafruit_BLE_UART::print(double, int)'`

If I do this instead, the code runs...

```
BTLEserial.print ((gps.location.lat(),6));
```

But I do not get the correct lat, instead I get this value `6.00000000`

I have tried to store the lat like this:

```
double myLat;

myLat = (gps.location.lat(), 6);
BTLEserial.print (myLat);
```

But with that myLat also has a value of `6.00000000` which is not correct.

I tried this as well:

```
char sValueOne[16], sValueTwo[16];
char sBuffer[33];

strcpy(sBuffer,dtostrf(((gps.location.lat(),6)), 15, 8, sValueOne));
strcat(sBuffer,",");
strcat(sBuffer,dtostrf(((gps.location.lng(),6)), 15, 8, sValueTwo));

BTLEserial.write((uint8_t *)sBuffer, strlen(sBuffer));
```

But with that I still get `6.00000000`. I am starting to run out of ideas now to make this work. I have tried to send it both directly and store it but nothing works successfully.

So how can I adjust the code to be able to print (or store) gps lat, lng value (TinyGPS++) with Bluetooth BLE nRF8001?

Appreciate every help and tips!

Comment: 6.000000 is the value of ((gps.location.lat(),6)) where 6 is the last item in the list. C/C++ is a strange language. Remove all the extra () and things will look better.

Comment: If i do `BTLEserial.print (gps.location.lng(),6); `i get a error: `no matching function for call to 'Adafruit_BLE_UART::print(double, int)'`

Comment: Add links to the libraries you are using.

Comment: myLat = (gps.location.lat(), 6); gives the value 6.0000 as explained above. It is not a list with the two values or a double with 6 digits.

Comment: For gps i use TinyGPS++, this: http://arduiniana.org/libraries/tinygpsplus/ and for my BLE i use this where you can see sample code also: https://learn.adafruit.com/getting-started-with-the-nrf8001-bluefruit-le-breakout/nrf-uart-in-detail

Comment: Yea exactly. And i want the correct lat/lng value so i am not sure on how to proceed to successfully connect that to my ble device when I write/print data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Arduino Stream/Print classes may sometime need some extra attention.

```
BTLEserial.println(gps.location.lat()`, 6);
```

The member function is available in the class Print but gets "hidden". You can help the compiler to find it with a prefix:

```
BTLEserial.Print::println(gps.location.lat()`, 6);
```

Cheers!

Comment: Hey! Thanks for this answer. Will try it in an hour

Comment: Hi! I get the correct value. However, it seems like it sends one number at a time. So when I recieve this on the app the value gets chopped up. So for example if the latitude is: 32.123456, it comes like this to the app: `3`, new row, `2`, new row etc.

Comment: I do not use `println` btw, instead `print`

Comment: That is a new question! Acknowledge the answer and ask a new one. I can help you with that :)

Comment: Ok Mikael! I will create a new thread regarding that issue. Thanks a lot for your example above to get the first part of the problem fixed. Will accept your answer and of course also upvote it!

Comment: Created a new post here: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/33115/how-can-i-adjust-my-code-so-that-the-value-that-i-print-with-my-ble-device-does if you want to check it out!

Comment: Yapp, answered that :)